# Issues with the REST client in Scala

Tags: apache, scala, rest

I am creating a Scala REST client using Apache HttpClient.
Here is my code.

```
import java.io._
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient

val output = getRestContent(myURL)

  /**
    * Returns the text content from a REST URL. Returns a blank String if there
    * is a problem.
    */
  def getRestContent(url:String): String = {
    val httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient()
    val httpResponse = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(url))
    val entity = httpResponse.getEntity()
    var content = ""
    if (entity != null) {
      val inputStream = entity.getContent()
      content = io.Source.fromInputStream(inputStream).getLines.mkString
      inputStream.close
    }
    httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown()
    return content
  }
```

The problem is that `Source` is marked in red in `io.Source`. It says `Cannot resolve symbol source`. Moreover `import java.io._` is marked as unused. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should:

- replace `import java.io._` with `import scala.io.Source`
- replace `io.Source.fromInputStream(...)` with `Source.fromInputStream(...)`

Answer (score 2):

Source class is not in java IO library

It is in

```
scala.io.Source
```

add this line and it will work

```
import scala.io.Source
```